# MS Project, add hours directly in resource usage

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010, ms-project-2016

at my work we use MS Project 2010 to run our Monday morning scheduling meeting, from Resource Usage view. In the version I inherited on my work computer, I can change the number of hours or add a new assignment and add hours to it without leaving Resource Usage view. We view it at the resolution of one week per column. This way we can quickly got through the list of employees, change the number of hours assigned to existing tasks or add new tasks on the fly to keep them each close to 40 hours of assigned work per week. Without this ability to edit the assigned hours per week in resource Usage view, we would have to run our meetings very differently.

We have several discs for MS Project 2010, but if I install on other computers, I cannot add hours right in Resource Usage view. I don't know what is special about the version of MS Project 2010 that I am using that I cannot get this function from other identical software. When I try to add or change hours in the columns, nothing happens, like my number lock key is off or something. I have also demoed MS Project 2016, Standard, and Pro, but I still cannot add hours directly into Resource Usage. Does anyone know if there is a setting to change that I don't recognize?

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure I totally understood the problem; however, I am pretty sure that it's not a version or application problem. 
I would give it a try and go to Project -> Change working Calendar and compare the settings between the version that you got on your working computer and a new installed version that you have on another computer.
I guess you need to setup a calendar or add some rules so that you get direct access on the Resource View. Which was already done on your inherited computer.